# Mouse click is failing to provide coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retrieve the mouse coordinates on the click event and display them to me. Currently it is not working.

This is my script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(
      $("#image").on({
        click: function (e) {
          x=e.pageX;
          alert(x);
        }
      })
    )
  </script>
  <img src="back.jpg" id="image" height="100px" width="100px" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me. Something is wrong somewhere else. https://jsfiddle.net/3m7urj5p/

Comment: Please change the subject first!

Comment: @synthet1c - untrue. You can do it either way. Your suggestion allows you to add one handler at a time, the other way allows you to add a bunch of them in a single call - 1 property per handler. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/3m7urj5p/1/

Comment: cheers for the heads up @enhzflep I have removed the comment and refreshed my knowledge of the method.

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/xev44y59/

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#image").click(function (e){
      x=e.pageX;
      alert(x);
   });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="http://ultraimg.com/images/2016/07/29/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" id="image" height="100px" width="100px" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code shared by OP is working fine.. Why to answer if so ?

Comment: @Rayon question was edited with ans. at the time i ans this ques. it was different. later ques was edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Shorthand function is not working for me as of OP for local while function block is working perfect but while creating jsFiddle both the function working fine [jsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4oxdc3tv/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image").click(function(e){
        x=e.pageX;
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: Code shared by OP is working fine.. Why to answer if so ?

Comment: Actually, that code was not working for me.. So i have implemented mine ... !!! Thanks for minus vote btw.

Comment: What was not working ? I have shared the fiddle in comments below question.. Check that out...

Comment: I have copied the above code into in my machine and checked but I am not getting a simple alert too. But your jsFiddle is working! so not sure what is the problem into the code i have copied before.

Comment: debug it, you are a developer by the way!

Comment: Yes, sure, I'll definitely try to check the different between both the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places on image</p>
<img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg"  width="100" height="100"   onclick="showCoords(event)"/>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}
</script>                
     </body>
        </html>
```